# change callback of socket.on("data", fn) nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

### Problem

I am using the node.js [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) library for sockets.

I have a `socket` variable that connects to a host and a port:

```
let socket;
socket = net.createConnection( connectOpts, () => {
    socket.on( "data", () => console.log("Hello World"));
} );
```

However, later on, I want to change the listener function. To achieve this I do:

```
socket.on( "data", () => console.log("Hello MARS"));
```

The problem is that when mu socket gets data, I see both `Hello World` and `Hello MARS` printed !

### Question

How do I change the listener function from `Hello World` to `Hello MARS`?

Comment: Copy that line and change `"data"` to something else, like `"data2"` and emit to this function.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using socket.io? If so you should be able to do `socket.off("data")` before you register the new event listener as it inherits from [`emitter`](https://github.com/component/emitter) you can call all of the methods emitter has.

Comment: @C0dekid there is no event "data2" in the net library. I don't think your approach would work.

Comment: @George I am using the `net` library from node.js (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html). I can't find a way of doing `socket.off` or `socket.removeListener` using it :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to first remove the old listener.

```
socket.removeListener("data", function(){
      socket.on( "data", () => console.log("Hello MARS"));
});
```

`socket.once("data", callback);` is also available if you want to receive a simple event and then remove the Listener.

Comment: I don't see these methods in the documentation :S 
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: How did you know the sockets class extends the [events class](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname), when this is not documented ?

Comment: it's not documented because it was prior to socket v1. I am afraid it no longer works... Didn't even check sadly and I can't make it work. Socket.off says it is not a function so it can't have just extended the events class. removeListener does not give an error but I am not sure if it works on the latest v2 version. It worked on 1.4.x last checked.

Comment: I tested socket.removeListener and it worked. That's why I accepted your answer :)

Comment: This is the kind of trolling i don't like in node.JS